# How to unset an entry in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I declare a new Array() and add a value, but then I want to remove that value, how do I do so? Setting the value = null simply creates a null value at that index, while removing that index with splice reduces the size of the array. See below:

```js
class CustomArray {
  constructor(size) {
    this.arr = new Array(size)
  }

  describe() {
    console.log(this.arr.length)
    this.arr.forEach(num => console.log(num))
  }

  insert(idx, val) {
    this.arr.splice(idx, 1, val)
  }

  remove(idx) {
    this.arr[idx] = null
  }

  remove2(idx) {
    this.arr.splice(idx, 1)
  }

}

let myArr = new CustomArray(20)
myArr.insert(3, 100)
myArr.remove(3)
myArr.describe() //outputs 20 for length and `null`


let mySecondArr = new CustomArray(20)
mySecondArr.insert(3, 100)
mySecondArr.remove(3) //ouputs 19 for length

//how do I remove all values AND retain length?
```

Comment: How does `mySecondArr` output 19 for length since it's the same as `myArr` and the same operations are called? `remove2` would reduce the array length, but the example provided is misleading. Anyway, you should use `delete this.arr[idx]` instead in order to avoid having `null`.

Comment: Do you really need a sparse array? What for, if I may ask? (cos you know, you could just set the index to undefined.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `delete` operator. `delete` will create an empty slot at that particular index. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Deleting_array_elements)

> When you delete an array element, the **array length is not affected**. This holds even if you delete the last element of the array.

```js
class CustomArray {
constructor(size) {
    this.arr = new Array(size)
}

describe() {
    console.log(this.arr.length)
    this.arr.forEach(num => console.log(num))
}

insert(idx, val) {
    this.arr.splice(idx, 1, val)
}

remove(idx) {
    delete this.arr[idx]
}

remove2(idx) {
    this.arr.splice(idx, 1)
}

}

let myArr = new CustomArray(20)
myArr.insert(3, 100)
myArr.remove(3)
myArr.describe()
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe `delete arr[i]` is what you're looking for. The length of the array doesn't change, the value is set to undefined, but it is also ignored by functions such as `map` and `forEach`, so they never run code for a deleted value.